# Program only prints out the first two lines of my code, and ignores the rest entirely

Tags: c++

So the problem I am facing here is that, the program runs only the first two lines of the code and entirely ignores the rest. I have tried rewriting it, I have also searched the internet for solution, but I found nothing and the problem continues to persist.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct customer{
    char A_ID[10];
    char pin[4];
    char amount[20];
    int input;
    int csnt;
}c;

int main()
{
 struct customer *p;
//  Welcome Note
 cout<<"Welcome to Absa,insert your card and enter you pin: "<<endl;
 cin.getline(c.pin,sizeof(c.pin));
 
//  Transaction Menu
 cout<<"1. Transfer"<<endl
 <<"2. Deposit"<<endl
 <<"3. Change pin"<<endl
 <<"4. Account Balance"<<endl;
 cin>>c.input;
 
//  Transaction Process
switch(c.input){
    case 1:
    cout<<"Enter amount: "<<endl;
    cin>>c.amount[9];
    cout<<"Enter recipient Account number: "<<endl;
    cin>>c.A_ID[10];
    cout<<"Payment of GHc "<<c.amount<<"made to "<<c.A_ID<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter 1 to confirm or 2 to cancel: "<<endl;
    cin>>c.csnt;
    if(c.csnt==1){
        cout<<"Transfer successful, thank you for Banking with Absa."<<endl;
    }
    else if(c.csnt==2){
        cout<<"Transfer cancelled, thank you for Banking with Absa."<<endl;
    }
}



return 0;
```

}

Comment: `p` is not allocated in provided code. But you are trying to access it in the very next line. Also `p->pin[4]` will also cause problem even if `p` is allocated

Comment: It seems you are combining C and C++. That's not a good idea. Choose one.

Comment: btw. "costumer" is a person who makes costumes. I guess you mean "customer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `p` variable has not been initialized yet:

```
struct customer *p;
```

That means it does not point to an instantiated object of type `customer`. So this is how you can create an object on the heap:

```
std::unique_ptr<customer> ptr { std::make_unique<customer>{ } };
```

`ptr` will handle the deletion of the `customer` object for you.

But there is really no need for you to use a pointer to `customer` in this case. Just create it on the stack:

```
customer cust; // here cust is stored on the stack so no need to deal with pointers
               // also struct keyword is not required here (in C++)
```

Then use the `.` operator to access its members like this:

```
std::cin >> cust.input;
```

**Note:** I don't understand what exactly you're trying to do here:

```
std::cin >>p->pin[4];
```

So my guess is that you are trying to assign a 4 digit number to `pin` array. This is not valid. But you may do this instead:

```
struct customer {
...
    char pin[4]; // use a char array
...
}

// get exactly 4 `char`s from the user and store in `pin`
std::cin.getline( cost.pin, sizeof(cust.pin) );

// or like this
std::string temp_pin;
std::getline( std::cin, temp_pin );

if (temp_pin.size() == 4)
{ // for example print success message;
    std::strncpy( cust.pin, temp_pin.data(), sizeof(cust.pin) );
}
else
{ // repeat the input process }
```

Also, you seem to mix C and C++ for no particular reason. Try to use only one of them to prevent any problems that might arise due to the different behaviors of C and C++ functions. Use `std::cout` or `std::format` (with C++20).

Here is the working version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <cstring>


struct Customer
{
    char A_ID[10 + 1] { }; // plus 1 for '\0' character
    char pin[4 + 1] { }; // plus 1 for '\0' character
    int amount { };
};


int main( )
{
    Customer cust;

    // Welcome Note
    std::cout << "Welcome to Absa, insert your card and enter you pin: \n";
    std::string pin; // temporary var for getting pin
    std::getline( std::cin, pin );
    std::strncpy( cust.pin, pin.data( ), sizeof( cust.pin ) - 1 ); // copy temp var to pin of cust
    cust.pin[4] = '\0'; // do this to make it null-terminated

    // Transaction Menu
    std::cout << "1. Transfer\n"
              << "2. Deposit\n"
              << "3. Change pin\n"
              << "4. Account Balance\n";

    std::string input { };
    std::getline( std::cin, input );

    // Transaction Process
    std::string amount; // temp var for amount
    std::string A_ID; // temp var for A_ID
    std::string csnt { };

    switch ( input[0] ) // compare the 1st char of input with test cases
    {
        case '1' :
            std::cout << "Enter amount: \n";
            std::getline( std::cin, amount );
            cust.amount = std::stoi( amount ); // convert string to integer

            std::cout << "Enter recipient Account number: \n";
            std::getline( std::cin, A_ID );
            std::strncpy( cust.A_ID, A_ID.data( ), sizeof( cust.A_ID ) - 1 );
            cust.A_ID[10] = '\0';

            std::cout << "Payment of GHc " << cust.amount<< " made to " << cust.A_ID << '\n';
            std::cout << "Enter 1 to confirm or 2 to cancel: \n";
            std::getline( std::cin, csnt );

            if ( csnt[0] == '1' )
            {
                std::cout << "Transfer successful, thank you for Banking with Absa.\n";
            }
            else if ( csnt[0] == '2' )
            {
                std::cout << "Transfer canceled, thank you for Banking with Absa.\n";
            }

            break;
        case '2' : // I leave these cases for you

        case '3' :

        case '4' :

        default:
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please mention the problem with `cost.pin[4]`

Comment: `costumer` has `int pin[4]`. So, `cost.pin[4]` isn't correct.

Comment: @kuro Right. added the necessary info.

Comment: ok, thanks. can you show me how to access the members of struct customer without a pointer.

Comment: @KB 21 Check the updated answer.

Comment: @digito_evo I added your updates to the program and now it prints the welcome note, but the rest still don't print. I also tried comment the welcome note, and running the rest, to my surprise it worked. It printed out the transaction menu and the first two lines in the transaction process, but it didn't accept any inputs.

Comment: @KB 21 I looked at your new code. You have messed up parts of the input process by applying `getline` to wrong statements. Ok I'll check it and try to make it work. Just wait a bit.

Comment: @digito_evo How about now ?

Comment: @KB 21 Check the updated answer, please.

Comment: Thanks, but i will want you to explain something to me. why did you a string csnt variable, while the value that will be store in that is of datatype value int.

Comment: @KB 21 First tell me what is the purpose of `csnt` in your code? I don't know. My guess was that it was suitable to make everything `std::string` and then convert to other types like `int` if necessary. Notice that my code receives `csnt` as a string. And then it compares it with characters  '1' and '2'.

Comment: @digito_evo csnt is meant to hold the approval of the user, where 1 represents confirm and 2 represents cancel.

Comment: @KB 21 Ok then my guess was right. Yes, it's suitable to make its data type string. No need for dealing with integers in that case. Dealing with characters (strings) is easier.